# How do you say “What is the length from the neck to the top of the hem?” in Italian?

Tags: translation

I am struggling to find out how to ask for two lengths on a vest.

[image: two lengths on a vest]

I have learnt that the question

> What is the length from the neck to the bottom of the hem?

is

> *Qual è la lunghezza dal collo al fondo dell'orlo?*

or

> *Qual è la lunghezza dal collo alla parte inferiore dell'orlo?*

(Please let me know if either one or both are is incorrect.)

But I am struggling to learn out how to say

> What is the length from the neck to the top of the hem?

Is it the following?

> *Qual è la lunghezza dal collo alla parte superiore dell'orlo?*

Comment: I don't think there is a specific term. I would omit “parte superiore” in the second case, because it's implicit.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it's not something really used. If you want to know the length of the vest/t-shirt or so on, you can ask about the length from the neck to the hem without saying anything else, so

> Qual è la lunghezza dal collo all'orlo?

Thus, it should be to the bottom of the hem, it's literally the total length of the clothes.
But, usually, we take measurements from the body, not from the clothing.
If you want to know the size of the hem, you can ask for the length from the neck to the hem and the length of the hem.

I wouldn't suggest to ask for the two different measurements to the hem. It's not  incorrect, but weird yes. Although, if you still want to ask as you stated, it will be clear to the interlocutor. For the first question, I would suggest the form

> Qual è la lunghezza dal collo alla parte inferiore dell'orlo?

"Al fondo" is not correct for this noun. "Fondo" refers more to something that has a depth, such as a bottle or an issue (in a figurative way). E.g.:

> Voglio arrivare in fondo alla questione

> I want to get to the bottom of the issue

Comment: You and @egreg in his comment to the question are saying two opposite things (i.e., in “Qual è la lunghezza dal collo all'orlo?” the hem itself is included or isn't). I'm Italian, but I don't know anything about clothing and their measurements, so I have no opinion on this.

Comment: As I wrote, it's not really used. But I also checked and if you mean "all'orlo" it's the length of the clothing, so the total length. Probably is something that changes according to the interlocutor, as it's not something of common use or that has a specificity. Also, saying "parte inferiore" or "parte superiore" it's even more uncommon.

Comment: Passando un momento all'italiano, intanto grazie per la risposta. Come dicevo, non me ne intendo specificamente di vestiario, e quindi pongo solo un dubbio. In generale, l'orlo dà l'idea di “tutto, fino all'estremità” (pieno fino all'orlo, sull'orlo del precipizio etc.). Ma paradossalmente, proprio per un indumento che ha un vero orlo, se uno chiedesse a me – che non me ne intendo – di misurarlo “da X all'orlo” mi porrei il problema se intenda orlo escluso o incluso, con una leggera sensazione che intenda “escluso” (cioè, fino a dove comincia l'orlo).

Comment: Neanch'io me ne intendo - ma magari una possibile soluzione potrebbe proprio essere "Qual è la lunghezza, orlo incluso?"

Comment: Generalmente si intende la lunghezza totale. Tuttavia, non essendo una cosa molto usata da noi, può essere che l'interlocutore capisca in modo diverso e quindi intenda fino all'inizio dell'orlo. La cosa più semplice direi che è chiedere la lunghezza totale del capo o, se si vuole, l'altezza. Citare l'orlo è superfluo